# Fluent NHibernate reflection mappings

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent, mappings

I'd like to parse through an Fluent NHibernate mapping file so I can get the table name and column names that are specified in there.

Loading the assembly and reflecting the type as ClassMap isn't a problem but that class only get methods to set the table and column names - nothing to get the names back again.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/), it looks like Table method has this signature:

```
public void Table(string tableName)
{
    this.attributes.Set<string>(x => x.TableName, tableName);
}
```

Columns will be a lot harder as it keeps properties, references, and collections separate. Eg.

```
protected virtual PropertyPart Map(PropertyInfo property, string columnName)
{
    PropertyPart propertyMap = new PropertyPart(property, typeof(T));
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(columnName))
    {
        propertyMap.Column(columnName);
    }
    this.properties.Add(propertyMap);
    return propertyMap;
}
```

In theory though you could get the private fields attributes, properties, and references via reflection and get the information that way.

Comment: Turns out I didn't need this as much as I thought. Apparently the CreateQuery method in nHibernate parses the string with the object name and maps the class field names to column names for you - still learning nhibernate :\ I've ended up writing my own Update method which takes a list of lambda expressions of fields to update and the new values and a list of lambda expressions for the conditional clause rather than using nHibernate to load each entity for each update.